# How to add bunch of external tools into Visual Studio IDE using Powershell command?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-extensions

I'm able to add third party tools by manually using External Tools - which is available in the Visual Studio IDE. But my requirement is, need to add more tools by executing powershell script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) to work with Visual Studio's  DTE object. See [here](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Documentation) and [here](http://basbossink.github.com/2011-12-19/ps4.netdevs-5-extending-vs/) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using an exported xml file, or just create on in your powershell script like what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340057/powershell-script-to-auto-add-visual-studio-external-tools-menu-options)

Basic jist of it:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# Determine fully qualified path to a temp file
$fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath() + [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString() + ".vssettings"; 

# Create User Settings file:
'<UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="9.0"/>
    <ToolsOptions/>
    <Category name="Environment_Group" RegisteredName="Environment_Group">
        <Category name="Environment_ExternalTools" Category="{E8FAE9E8-FBA2-4474-B134-AB0FFCFB291D}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_ExternalTools" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Command">powershell.exe</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Arguments">"&amp; ''$(ProjectDir)\Myscript.ps1''"</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.InitialDirectory">"$(ProjectDir)"</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.SourceKeyName"/>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.UseOutputWindow">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.PromptForArguments">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.CloseOnExit">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.IsGUIapp">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.SaveAllDocs">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.UseTaskList">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Unicode">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Package">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.NameID">0</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="ToolNames">Launch Powershell</PropertyValue>
        </Category>
    </Category>
</UserSettings>' >> $fileName


# Perform the import of the custom tool
$project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/import:""$fileName""");

"--Remove file"
Remove-Item -path $fileName
```

**NOTE:** In order to utilize the Visual Studio DTE, you need to use a third party extension such as PSCX (PowerShell Community Extension)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19098502)

Comment: @JasonAller Added the main script content