# PowerShell script to auto-add Visual Studio "External Tools..." menu options?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

We use Nuget to manage our internal toolchain and installing some PowerShell scripts, which we currently manually include in Visual Studio via custom "External Tools..." menu options.

I would LOVE it if there was a PowerShell Script to automatically add menu options that normally require the "External Tools..." dialog.  Is there an API to do this?

I have scripted out most of our Dev On-boarding process to automagically configure dev machines, save for a few oddities like this.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible.

In the NuGet package's `init.ps1` file, which has access to the DTE object, a new tool can be imported from a dynamically created file containing User Settings configuration that's then deleted after the user settings are imported.

Here's an example of a command to do imports. The example launches Powershell, executing a script in the root directory of a project. Note that I've used VS v9.0 for greatest backwards-compatibility, but it'd be possible to just export the existing tools menu configuration in v15.0 (or newer), and just replace the content in the file below accordingly.

**init.ps1 file content**

```
# NuGet Package installation script. Run 
# first time NuGet package installed to solution. 
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# Determine fully qualified path to a temp file
$fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath() + [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString() + ".vssettings"; 

# Create User Settings file:
'<UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="9.0"/>
    <ToolsOptions/>
    <Category name="Environment_Group" RegisteredName="Environment_Group">
        <Category name="Environment_ExternalTools" Category="{E8FAE9E8-FBA2-4474-B134-AB0FFCFB291D}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_ExternalTools" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Command">powershell.exe</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Arguments">"&amp; ''$(ProjectDir)\Myscript.ps1''"</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.InitialDirectory">"$(ProjectDir)"</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.SourceKeyName"/>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.UseOutputWindow">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.PromptForArguments">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.CloseOnExit">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.IsGUIapp">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.SaveAllDocs">true</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.UseTaskList">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Unicode">false</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.Package">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="Launch Powershell.NameID">0</PropertyValue>
            <PropertyValue name="ToolNames">Launch Powershell</PropertyValue>
        </Category>
    </Category>
</UserSettings>' >> $fileName


# Perform the import of the custom tool
$project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/import:""$fileName""");

"--Remove file"
Remove-Item -path $fileName
```

**MyProject.nuspec (partial) content**

In the `.nuspec` file, ensure that the `init.ps1` file is included. In the case below, the source for the init.ps1 is in a Visual Studio project named 'MyProject' in the 'Scripts' folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
      ...
    </metadata>
    <files>
        ...
        <!-- NuGet Package installation script. Run first time NuGet package installed to solution. -->
        <file src="Scripts\init.ps1" target="tools\init.ps1" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Comment: This might be the most amazing contribution to StackOverflow... ever.  You, sir, deserve a hat.

Comment: @JohnZabroski Thanks John. I implemented a similar thing with the help of other links and suggestions on SO. However, the more I think about it, the more I think that this isn't the best way of doing this... as when a project is installed the first time, the script would be run, but for other devs pulling the project from source control, I don't think the script would run. It might be more appropriate to create a simple installer using InnoSetup that runs the same powershell script (in answer above) to do this. Then installation of the External Tool isn't tied to installing a Nuget package...

Comment: I thought about your comment, and I guess my only question is, how is using a NuGet package any different from xunit.runner being installed via NuGet?

Comment: @JohnZabroski They're the same. What I'm suggesting is /not/ using NuGet to install the External Tools menu item, as options on the Tools menu shouldn't be tied to a single project. Further, with newer versions of NuGet, any Powershell scripts are only installed the first time the package is installed (so if it's already there, as in when packages are checked into source control), then the script to add the menu would never be run. I suggest using a non-NuGet method to do the menu item installation...

Comment: The NuGet people never cease to amaze me with their bad ideas on package management. I did not know about that PowerShell scripts rule. There surely must be a way to override that crazy behavior? Paket is probably the way to go from here on out.  Even NuGet.org now recognizes Paket as an option for installing nupkg's

Comment: With Visual Studio Codespaces on GitHub, it would make more sense to move this to a devInit.json file... thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for same thing and so far it looks like there is no way how to interact with IDE from PowerShell. But I found this package http://www.nuget.org/packages/StudioShell.Provider/ and at the first sight it allows you to do advanced stuff which you can do only with plugins and extensions. But in my opinion it is little bit overkill for this problem.

Comment: I found a possible way awhile back I have yet to try.  Basically, (1) Tools -> Import and Export Settings... (2) Export environment settings, Next, All Settings -> General Settings -> External Tools List
Give it a try and let me know if it works...